# Website not updating on one particular machine

Tags: reactjs, macos, caching, dns, netlify

*Update*
*I tried the site on a guest user on my Mac and it flipping worked! So the issue has been narrowed down to my user alone*

I have a react website I'm hosting on Netlify, and everything is perfect when I update it EXCEPT when I view it on the machine I made it on, it won't update.

I host 4 websites on this Netlify account that are built on this machine and this is the only one that has this issue.

Here is a list of things I have tried:

- Empty Cache and Hard reload on Chrome
- Clearing entire browsing hotory and cache
- Different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Brave)
- Incognito windows
- Flushing DNS using the following commands:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

and I have also tried

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

- All of the above with power downs inbetween!

I am at a complete loss! When I try the website on my wife's PC it works, 4 of my colleagues Macs it works, my Google Pixel and my colleagues iPhone, they all work, so I know the issue is my machine.

My Machine is a 2020 M1 Macbook Air

Any radical ideas? At this point I'll try most things!